# TCGAbiolinks: GDCprepare Function Issue

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am planning to use TCGAbiolinks to Prepare expression matrix.And I am trying to run the PAADRnaseqSE <- GDCprepare(query_RNA_Seq) function after I have downloaded the Gene expression quantification data, but every time I run the function, it produces the error message as follow:

```
> PAADRnaseqSE <- GDCprepare(query_RNA_Seq)
  |=================================================================================================================================| 100%
Downloading genome information (try:0) Using: Homo sapiens genes (GRCh37.p13)
Starting to add information to samples
 => Add clinical information to samples
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <?xml version="1.0" ?> <respons
                     (right here) ------^
```

Anything I can do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the package:

```
devtools::install_github(repo = "BioinformaticsFMRP/TCGAbiolinks")
```

If that does not work, there is also another branch with a different code (using this package https://github.com/Bioconductor/GenomicDataCommons). Could you try installing it and see if the bug persists?

```
devtools::install_github(repo = "BioinformaticsFMRP/TCGAbiolinks",ref = "GenomicDataCommons" )
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar problem, i could not solve it with;

```
devtools::install_github(repo = "BioinformaticsFMRP/TCGAbiolinks", dependencies = T)
```

neither from RStudio nor R terminal. But when i do it as super user;

```
sudo R devtools::install_github(repo = "BioinformaticsFMRP/TCGAbiolinks", dependencies = T)
```

the problem solved.

Comment: this is not a solution, but further clarifying the question.

Please put this is a comment instead.